# ‘myV’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I have a header file : **a.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    int m_a;
    public:
      A(int a); 
};
```

and a source file **a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string>myV;
myV.push_back("a");

A::A(int a)
{
  m_a = a;
}
```

I am compiling the above program on CentOs-7.2 using: **g++ a.cpp**

On compiling the above program I am getting this error:

```
a.cpp:8:1: error: ‘myV’ does not name a type
 myV.push_back("a");
```

Anyone can help me in this error ?

Comment: You can't run code outside any function, so the compiler is treating `myV` as a type while parsing.

Comment: You can _declare_ things outside a function, but you can't call functions on them (i.e. your declaration of `myV` is fine, but the use of `push_back` is not)

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have pointed out, you can't call functions on an object outside a function. You can only declare objects. Fortunately, you can initialise `myV` in the same statement:

```
vector<string> myV { "a" };
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not a scripting language, most of the runtime methods should be put into a function call.

You can only define global variables, functions and class outside of function calls

```
A::A(int a)
{
  vector<string>myV;
  myV.push_back("a");
  m_a = a;
}
```